# Can't retrieve data from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I my code I can't retrieve data from Firebase.

When I am adding values on Firebase I do see that items added on Firebase database on my console.

Also I had created listener `.childAdded` and I see that items added on Firebase Database.

But when I call `.value` it retrieves `nil` result.

I don't know what's happening there.

Here is my code.

```
class FirebaseManager {

    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var database: DatabaseHandle?

    static let shared: FirebaseManager = {
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
        return FirebaseManager()
    }()

    private func initFireabase() {
        ref =  Database.database().reference(withPath: AMUtils.getUDID())        
    }

    func addToDB(composition: Composition) {
        initFireabase()
        ref?.child(String(composition.id)).child("id").setValue(composition.id)
        ref?.child(String(composition.id)).child("title").setValue(composition.title)       
    }

    func removeFromDb(composition: Composition) {
        ref?.child(String(composition.id)).removeValue()
    }

    func getCompositonFromDB(onResult: @escaping ([Composition]) -> Void){
        initFireabase()
        var compositions: [Composition] = []
        database = ref?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            compositions.removeAll()
            let value = snapshot.value as? JSON
            compositions.append(AudioListParser.parseObject(json: value!))
            self.ref?.removeObserver(withHandle: self.database!)
            onResult(compositions)
        })
    }
}
```

getCompositonFromDB() I am calling when I am starting the view controller and this is always nil even I have values on database

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong here?

[image]

Comment: `snapshot.value` in your case exposes an `NSDictionary<String,AnyObject?>`. I'm not sure what the `JSON` type is, but it's not a type that `FIRDataSnapshot.value` returns: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#value

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen public typealias JSON = [String: Any]

Comment: What does *this is always nil* mean? If you add the line *print(snapshot)* immediately after the the observe line, what prints?

Comment: actually I found the problem .childAdded and .value returning different results

Comment: That's not a problem - that's by design. .childAdded iterates over all of the child nodes one at a time. .value returns everything in the node. See [Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

Answer (score 0):

have you changed the rules for database??
like if you are authenticating you should set not null for both write and read and if you are not authenticating then keep it null for both, because doing exact opposite of above could cause some errors!!

Comment: yeah I changef it {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}